# SELECT not null column from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a table that has two columns, one of which will be `NULL` and one will not, what I would like to do is something like:

```
SELECT (column1 OR column2) AS value
```

But I need to retrieve the value that is not null. I feel like this is probably an easy question, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2) AS value
```

or

```
SELECT IFNULL(column1, column2) AS value
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL THEN column1 ELSE column2 END AS value
```

or

```
SELECT IF(column1 IS NOT NULL, column1, column2) AS value
```

Comment: @Foo_Chow: not only about sql, but about a particular mysql dialect. #2 and #4 are mysql-specific solutions. And #1 and #3 would work in most DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, you can use the **IFNULL** function. In SQL Server, you can use **ISNULL** function.